# href link won't go to top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

In my site, http://lol.bu.edu/ctl/home-2/, when I click on the Questrom Team Learning button, it goes to the link correctly, which is http://lol.bu.edu/ctl/home-2/#after_layer_slider_1.

However, if I manually type in the link or refresh the page in mobile (screen width less than 750px), it goes to the same height location for the link as it would normally go to for a full width (which is further down on the page for mobile).

Sometimes when I refresh the page it briefly goes to the right location before scrolling down again.

Is this a javascript problem and how would I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your page  `http://lol.bu.edu/ctl/home-2/#after_layer_slider_1`
remove the `#after_layer_slider_1` at the end of the url. The `#after_layer_slider_1` is targeting a location on your page and is why it is moving down. Jus t simply remove that part of the url and it will load at the top of the page.

and if you do not want to have it do that at all ctr+f and look for "after_layer_slider_1" in your javasrcipt, delete that part and it will stop doing the page scroll alltogether.

Answer (score 0):

Just feast your eyes, on below, bro

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[rel="relativeanchor"]').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
        }, 500);
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

[**Live Demo (smooth scroll to top)**](http://jsfiddle.net/francescov/4DcNH/)